# LibTiff: Tiff to pdf

Tags: batch-file, command, tiff, libtiff

Following command converts input.tiff file into pdf:

```
tiff2pdf −o output.pdf input.tiff
```

There are more than 100 tiff files in a directory. How to convert all those in one pdf file in a batch file?

```
tiff2pdf −o output.pdf input1.tiff input2.tiff... // ??
```

#### Update:

Libtiff's utility tiff2pdf does not support converting multiple files. I switched to ImageMagick and used following command to convert tiff files in one pdf.

```
gm.exe convert 1.tif 2.tif output.pdf
```

#### Question:

I have more than 100 files in a directory how to use this command in batch to convert all 100 files into pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gm.exe convert *.tif output.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`tiffcp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tiffcp) to combine multiple `.tif` files. And then use [`tiff2pdf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tiff2pdf) to convert the combined file to `.pdf`

1. `$ tiffcp *.tif intermediate.tif`
2. `$ tiff2pdf -o output.pdf intermediate.tif`